# Umbraco TinyMCE - not showing absolute URLs in Insert/Update link

Tags: tinymce, umbraco

this has been driving me crazy for a few hours, I managed to fix it on my local development machine and of course when I put it to live it's not working.

Here is what I did in my Umbraco set up:

in the Config/tinyMceConfig.Config I added:

```
<config key="relative_urls">false</config>

<config key="convert_urls">false</config>

<config key="remove_script_host">false</config>
```

I also amended the Javascript code in insertLink.aspx to set localUrl to blank as this made it work on the dev machine. Does anyone know how to fix this really stupid bug on my live server?

Thanks

Comment: Did you "touch" the web.config after making the changes to the `tinyMceConfig.config`?

Comment: I re-saved it and....nothing!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, **you could not override "remove_script_host" because it is hardcoded** in umbraco.editorControls.tinyMCE3.TinyMCE :

Line 250: `config.Add("remove_script_host", "true");`.

And when you add new value to config file - you will get **"true,false"** instead of **"false"**, because of **NameValueCollection** used.

And as we know, when you add **2 items with same key** to NameValueCollection, as result you will have **concatenation of that two values, with comma separator**.

So don't waste your time on finding out what's wrong with your "remove_script_host" configuration.

Comment: +1 for mentioning concatenation, it is a bug in tinyMCE3 editor