# Force Absolute URLS in TInyMCE

Tags: tinymce, umbraco

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Umbraco TinyMCE - not showing absolute URLs in Insert/Update link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353953/umbraco-tinymce-not-showing-absolute-urls-in-insert-update-link)

Hi I am using Umbraco and for some reason I cannot get the TinyMCE to use absolute urls. I have change the tinymce config and nothing seems to work.
Does anyone have any ideas?

I am using umbraco 4.7